# What is the new way to change the nav text color with Bootstrap 5?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use Bootstrap 5 and here is my problem. I was changing the color of the `nav li a` element directly in the css with Bootstrap 4. But now, with B5 this way does not work.
Do you guys know how can I change it please ?

Here is an example.

```css
.navbar-brand {
    color: #3DB9C3 !important;
}

.banniere nav li a { 
     color: #3DB9C3 !important; 
} 

.banniere nav li a:hover {
    color: #0D4B50 !important;
}

/*Screen < to 1250px*/
@media (max-width: 1250px) { 
    .nav-item:hover {
        background-color: #3DB9C3;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg banniere border-bottom">
        <div class="container">
         <a class="navbar-brand">Name Test</a>          
                    <button class="navbar-toggler float-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" style="outline-color: #3DB9C3;">
                          <span style="color: #3DB9C3"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></span>
                    </button>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-center" id="navbarResponsive">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                            <li class="nav-item active me-3">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Test1
                                    <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item me-3">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Test2</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item me-3">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Test3</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item me-3">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Test4</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Cordially

Comment: Looks like you code is working and nav text color is blue, What do you want then?

Comment: If you check the css, the color should be `#3DB9C3` and not that blue. Since Bootstrap 5 its not possible to change it the way I'm doing it.

Comment: #3DB9C3 is actually variant of blue only

Comment: I did change the color with red, and still nothing... I really don't know how to change this color...

Comment: When I move the css code into the html code with the `<style>`, it work... very strange...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `!important;` like this

```
nav li a {
    color:#3DB9C3 !important;
}
```

There are many ways of doing this..

**1.** if ur specifying CSS in style-sheet u can load it after bootstrap 5 ,that way you can use style without `!important;`

**2.** You can add one more specifier like

```
.my-navbar nav li a {
    color:#3DB9C3 !important;
}
```

where `my-navbar` class can be added in **parent** div

I told to give class to parent, but u cave class to **nav** itself
when u give class to **nav** your selector should be like this

```
nav.banniere li a { 
     color: #3DB9C3 !important; 
}
```

```css
.navbar-brand {
    color: #3DB9C3 !important;
}
nav.banniere li a { 
     color: red ; 
} 

 nav.banniere li a:hover {
    color: green ;
}

/*Screen < to 1250px*/
@media (max-width: 1250px) { 
    .nav-item:hover {
        background-color: #3DB9C3;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg banniere border-bottom">
        <div class="container">
         <a class="navbar-brand">Name Test</a>          
                    <button class="navbar-toggler float-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" style="outline-color: #3DB9C3;">
                          <span style="color: #3DB9C3"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></span>
                    </button>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-center" id="navbarResponsive">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                            <li class="nav-item active me-3">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Test1
                                    <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item me-3">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Test2</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item me-3">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Test3</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item me-3">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Test4</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's what I do. In my example, I'm doing this : `.banniere nav li a { color: #3DB9C3 !important; } and .banniere nav li a:hover{color: #0D4B50 !important;}` and still now working... Bootstrap 5 is really strange

Comment: @Balaure if u find value in answer plz mark correct answers.! or if u have further query u can ask

Comment: I've tried what you've say, and still not working :/ I've edited my code in the 1st comment with your suggestion